# Air-coupled microphone

Tags: sound

Does anyone know what the heck is a coupled-air microphone? I know that they were used for recording internal body sounds in papers like [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19002477) and [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2036.2010.04559.x/full). I googled the term, but I couldn't find any circuitry schema or place where to buy one. Are they some kind of diaphragm, condenser or contact microphone?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-contact_ultrasound) I would guess that it really is just a way of saying that no gels were used as a coupling medium.

Comment: Makes sense, but how are they attached to body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem you are aiming at is connected with Phonocardiography (recording bodily sounds). Traditionally contact sensors (such as stethoscopes) were used for this task, but problem is that you must raise and lower the device between two measurements. In case of air-coupled microphone (meaning that it is not touching the body) you can move it constantly, performing a continuous measurement.

Obviously there is some disadvantage, such that it is prone to environmental noise, but shielding (tubes) are used, as well as microphone arrays for noise cancellation. Problem of coupling the membrane with patient body is very hard to tackle, as big mismatch exists between air characteristic impedance and body impedance, but using a conical shape is helping to transform these impedances.

What kind of microphones were being used? These are almost the same used widely in recordings:

- Condenser
- Electret
- Piezoelectric

Some of these were adapted for recording of infra-sounds, i.e. Brüel & Kjaer, model 4117 or other great, 4135. Although people are also using quite cheap electret microphones for this task.

This article can shed some light on that:

> [Algernon D., et al. - *Signal Processing for Air-Coupled Impact-Echo
>   using Microphone
>   Arrays*](http://www.ndt.net/article/wcndt2012/papers/410_wcndtfinal00410.pdf).

Comment: Nice! I was trying to find some alternatives to contact mics (which have a very tiny sound problem). I have been struggling the limitation using amplifiers like [this](http://www.megalithia.com/sounds/tech/piezo/opamp.html), but haven't have success yet :(